# How to query the Sql azure federation tables

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-sql-database

I have been through many federation tutorials, but all of them are dealing with how to get data into the federations and somehow missing the part that explains how to query the data after it's there.

I found in the documentation that you cannot join between federation tables.  I wonder, how exactly do I query the tables? Will my current SPs continue to work with the new federation DBs? Is there any advanced tutorial on how to query the data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to keep calling the command that connects you to the correct federation first.  Then you can query within that federation to your heart's content:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh597457.aspx

This is important for folks using ADO.NET, data readers, etc.

There are also some considerations for Entity-Framework folks:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh689720.aspx

Answer (score 2):

if you're looking at comnbining results from federation members, have a look at how to issue fan-out queries against federation members.

see: 
[Introduction to Fan-out Queries for Federations in SQL Azure (Part 1): Scalable Queries over Multiple Federation Members, MapReduce Style!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2011/12/29/introduction-to-fan-out-queries-querying-multiple-federation-members-with-federations-in-sql-azure.aspx)

[Fan-out Querying for Federations in SQL Azure (Part 2): Scalable Fan-out Queries with TOP, ORDER BY, DISTINCT and Other Powerful Aggregates, MapReduce Style!](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cbiyikoglu/archive/2012/01/19/fan-out-querying-in-federations-part-ii-summary-queries-fanout-queries-with-top-ordering-and-aggregates.aspx)